# How to display zero rows for non-existent values SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the below SQL which generates the Account type and their region and type. Currently, my table has only Type 1, Type 2, Type 4, and Type 6. But I would like it to show me all the types: 1,2,3,4,5,6 where 3 and 5 would have zero.

So my results would look like this

[image]

```
select *
from (values ('Account Exec','US','Type 1',12)
           , ('Account Exec','US','Type 2',34)
           , ('Account Exec','US','Type 4',24)
           , ('Account Exec','US','Type 6',32)
           , ('Account Exec','Europe','Type 1',35)
           , ('Account Exec','Europe','Type 4',43)
           , ('Account Exec','Europe','Type 6',45)
           , ('Account Exec','Others','Type 1',23)
           , ('Account Exec','Others','Type 4',23)
           , ('Account Exec','Others','Type 6',54) 
    ) a(TE,REG,ATTAIN,total)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the domain of discourse and then left join that with your sample data. Your sample data did not include all types so I hard-coded that one:

```
with types (attain) as ( values ('Type 1'),('Type 2'),('Type 3'),('Type 4'),('Type 5'),('Type 6') )
    , sample (te, reg, attain, total) as (
        select *
        from (values ('Account Exec','US','Type 1',12)
           , ('Account Exec','US','Type 2',34)
           , ('Account Exec','US','Type 4',24)
           , ('Account Exec','US','Type 6',32)
           , ('Account Exec','Europe','Type 1',35)
           , ('Account Exec','Europe','Type 4',43)
           , ('Account Exec','Europe','Type 6',45)
           , ('Account Exec','Others','Type 1',23)
           , ('Account Exec','Others','Type 4',23)
           , ('Account Exec','Others','Type 6',54) 
        ) a(TE,REG,ATTAIN,total) )
    , te_reg(te, reg, attain) as (
         select distinct s.te, s.reg, t.attain
         from sample s
         cross join types t
 )
select t.te, t.reg, t.attain, coalesce(s.total, 0)
from te_reg t
left join sample s
    using (te, reg, attain)
order by t.te, t.reg, t.attain;

te  reg attain  coalesce
Account Exec    Europe  Type 1  35
Account Exec    Europe  Type 2  0
Account Exec    Europe  Type 3  0
Account Exec    Europe  Type 4  43
Account Exec    Europe  Type 5  0
Account Exec    Europe  Type 6  45
Account Exec    Others  Type 1  23
Account Exec    Others  Type 2  0
Account Exec    Others  Type 3  0
Account Exec    Others  Type 4  23
Account Exec    Others  Type 5  0
Account Exec    Others  Type 6  54
Account Exec    US  Type 1  12
Account Exec    US  Type 2  34
Account Exec    US  Type 3  0
Account Exec    US  Type 4  24
Account Exec    US  Type 5  0
Account Exec    US  Type 6  32
```

Note that the example is for postgres, so you may have to adjust the syntax a bit. See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5Zxjtt_Z)

If you table contains all types you can do a distinct from there instead of enumerating them like I did in types.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this:

```
select *
from (values ('Account Exec','US','Type 1',12),
             ('Account Exec','US','Type 2',34),
             ('Account Exec','US','Type 3',0),
             ('Account Exec','US','Type 4',24),
             ('Account Exec','US','Type 5',0),
             ('Account Exec','US','Type 6',32))
```

[image]